# PrevState does not update state value immediately in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to update state value immediately with the use of prevState but value does not change. I know seState is asycnc function but If I use prevState, should not be update immediately? Where I do the mistake?

```
   count: 0
```

```
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      count: prevState +1
    }));

    console.log(this.state.count+" count")
```

Comment: *"but If I use prevState, should not be update immediately?"* No. It doesn't matter what form of `setState` you use. It's always async.

Comment: state is updated asynchronously whether you use the previous state or not. State and props within a specific render of a component are constant.

Comment: I understand thanks, So is there any why to get value immediately after updating state?

Comment: _o is there any why to get value immediately after updating state?_ - you can't get the updated value of state within the same render but you could pass a second optional callback to `this.setState`. This callback is called after the state has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok You have to understand the following thing

```
function foo() {
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    count: prevState + 1,
  }));
}

//call function first and then log
foo()
console.log(count) // here you will get your answer
```

Remember any number of this.setState statement in one parent function will execute after the parent function ends

Answer (score 1):

As you know setState is async. But also learn if you pass callback in setstate then you need to call `prevState.something` as `something is your state`. SO basically you need to do this:

```
this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        count: prevState.count + 1
      }),
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.count + " count");
      }
    );
```

Here is POC:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Test extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState(
      (prevState) => ({
        count: prevState.count + 1
      }),
      () => {
        console.log(this.state.count + " count");
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.count}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-beaver-cu4bl?file=/src/App.js:0-596

Answer (score 1):

it should be
prevState.count + 1